# Connect Remote Queue Manager in a container via MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to access queue manager via mq explorer but getting an error:

- Could not establish a connection to the queue manager - reason 2538. (AMQ4059)
  Could not establish a connection to the queue manager - reason 2538. (AMQ4059)
- Severity: 10 (Warning)
- Explanation: The attempt to connect to the queue manager failed. This could be because the queue manager is incorrectly configured to allow a connection from this system, or the connection has been broken.
- Response: Try the operation again. If the error persists, examine the problem determination information to see if any information has been recorded.

I followed all the instructions in https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623113 in order to allow mq explorer to be able to access mq server but still no luck.

IBM MQ Server details:

- Version: 8
- OS: Centos
- Running in a docker container
- Using port 1417 since my 1414 port is not available for another MQ server
- Listener is up an running and pointing port 1417
- Channel is defined as it is described in the link that I shared (I disabled all security features as it is described)
- I have a sample Java App that I can put/get messages and it is working fine

MQ Explorer details:

- Also running in another docker container thanks to
  https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/tree/master/incubating/mq-explorer
- I can telnet MQ Server from xterm so there is no issue about the connectivity
- Although I disabled all security features, I also tried to create the same username on server as well as my xterm but it did not work either.

I was expecting to get an error message in my MQ Server to understand the issue but surprisingly there is no error message at all ...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPNw4.png)

Comment: Which version of MQ v8 are you using for the queue manager (for example 8.0.0.3 or 8.0.0.11)?  Check that `DIS QMGR CHLEV` is set to `ENABLED` if it is not, then enable it with `ALTER QMGR CHLEV(ENABLED)`.  Reproduce the failure and check to see any messages are generated in the `SYSTEM.ADMIN.CHANNEL.EVENT` queue.  If you see messages then run this:  `/opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsevt -m QMGRNAME -q SYSTEM.ADMIN.CHANNEL.EVENT`.  Look at the last few messages to see if they correspond to your MQ Explorer and explain why you see a failure.

Comment: Both the comment from @JoshMc and the answer from Roger are suggesting you are having security issues, but reason code 2358 is MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE, so you should double check your connectivity. You have suggested that you have not got connectivity issues because you can telnet to the QMgr - is this telnet from the same machine/docker container as the MQ Explorer is running in? You don't show us a screen shot of your MQ Explorer connection settings - we can only assume you have input the correct port there?

Comment: @JoshMc, many thanks for the advice! I followed your recommendations and as you mentioned, a record appeared in `SYSTEM.ADMIN.CHANNEL.EVENT` queue. Unfortunately, I do not have `amqsevt` script. I do have `/opt/mqm/samp` folder but no `bin` folder. I also check `/opt/mqm/bin` folder too but no luck. I will try to find `amqsevt`. Many thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JoshMc, I should tell you my steps since I have feeling that the message in the queue might not be related to my issue. I changed `CHLEV` value in my queue manager and tried to login from mq explorer again. Nothing happened. Then, I thought that I should restart my queue manager so I did. Then, started my listener and then I thought I should start my channel as well since it is necesary for remote queue so I thought that it might be a requirement for mq explorer as well .. Anyway, I think the message in `SYSTEM.ADMIN.CHANNEL.EVENT` is most likely from my start channel command :(

Comment: @JoshMc, I just stopped/started my channel and the number of messages becomes 3

Comment: @MoragHughson, I just added a screenshot. Right Top: Xterm, I did telnet from this window to 0.0.0.0 1417 | Right Bottom: MQ Server connection | Left: MQ Explorer window that opens thanks to XQuartz

Comment: What do you do to ensure the explorer container can access the queue manager container on port 1417?

Comment: And you are correct, any start or stop command against a channel will result in a channel event message being generated.  Generally a SVRCONN channel is in a INACTIVE state which means it is ready to receive a connection, the only time you would need to start a SVRCONN is if it was in a STOPPED status because you previously stopped it.

Comment: If you are able to start a bash in both the queue manager and MQ explorer container, then a better test is to perform the telnet on the MQ explorer bash targeting the same IP and port you specify in MQ explorer, assuming this connects fine, then go to the queue manager bash and execute `netstat -an|grep 1417` and look for an `ESTABLISHED` connection, if you do not see one then your connection from the MQ explorer container is not getting to the queue manger container.

Comment: What is IP address 0.0.0.0? Are you sure that is the correct IP address you should be using?

Comment: You won't see any errors recorded at the queue manager for this particular error case because the client (MQ Explorer) is not reaching your queue manager as reported by the MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE (2358) return code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stated that your queue manager(s) are running in a container and your MQ Explorer is running in another container. I've noticed you've supplied 0.0.0.0 as your hostname but the container where MQ Explorer is running has no queue managers running on it!

If you run the following command (replacing  with the ID of the container running your queue managers) you should get the IP address of the container on the docker subnet. Try using that IP address in MQ Explorer instead of 0.0.0.0:

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" <QM container>
```

If your container is on a different docker network then you will need to run the following replacing  with the name you gave the docker network:

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.<Network Name>.IPAddress }}" <QM container>
```

Additionally, when you created your queue manager container did you remember to expose the 1417 port you are trying to use? By default the `mq-container` sample only exposes the following ports: 1414, 9157 & 9443. When you ran the container you would of needed to expose the ports but supplying `--publish-all --publish 1417` when you ran the container. For example:

```
docker run -d -e LICENSE=accept --publish-all --publish 1417 ibmcom/mq
```

Comment: Many thanks Rob! This solved my problem. Just to be clear, I have already published port 1417 to my host but I was using 0.0.0.0 instead of 172.17.0.2

Comment: Glad to hear it solved your problem. This slack overflow document details what to do when someone answers a question and how to mark the problem as solved: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

In this case you should "accept" this answer to show it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have attempted to connect your MQ Explorer to your queue manager using the following connection details:-

- Host name or IP address: 0.0.0.0
- Port number: 1417
- Server-connection channel: SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN

and you have received return code MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE(2358) which says that the network address is not reachable.

Common reasons for this error include not having a TCP.IP listener running using that port, but you have told us you have got a listener running.

The IP address you have used is the problem. Change the IP address in your MQ Explorer configuration to the actual IP address where the queue manager is running. If the MQ Explorer and Queue Manager are on the same machine (in the same container), you can use the localhost hostname or the IP address 127.0.0.1, otherwise, please use the assigned IP address for the machine. From your screenshot it appears that this might be a 192.168.* address.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 seems to be a docker reference to the real ip of the host from what i read.   Unless you tell docker to route a host port to the docker ip it does not.

Comment: On a normal linux host 0.0.0.0 went to 127.0.0.1 for me.

Comment: On Windows it doesn't seem to be setup by default.

Comment: Not sure from your comments whether you think this is or is not the problem?

Comment: I think it may have to do with the container ports that are exposed or not exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of IBM MQ your queue manager is running under.  i.e. v7.5, v8.0, v9.0 or v9.1.

Did you give yourself CHLAUTH permission to use the SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel?  Most likely you are being blocked by the backstop rule.

Also, if you are on IBM MQ v8.0 or higher then then CONNAUTH could be blocking you.

Here are 2 good links to walk you through your issue.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/blocked_by_chlauth_why?lang=en

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q001110_.htm

Comment: MQ version is 8.0.0.4. In the link that I shared (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623113), it recommends:


* c. For MQ 7.1 and later, and if you need to allow remote connections by an MQ Administrator.


* d. For MQ 8.0 and later, and if you want the password to be optional for an MQ Administrator.

* I did both of them so CONNAUTH is not an issue for me but I will take a look to your link in case I might catch something. Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: I just read the links but they are all related if CHLAUTH(ENABLED) which is not the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me after exploring further:

The ip shall be you own pc/laptop IP address assigned, find by

- $ifconfig -a

en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
ether f0:18:98:12:39:6f
inet6 fe80::183a:3111:162c:e9f9%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6
inet 192.168.1.65 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255

IP 192.168.1.65
Port 1414
Channel DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN

Find right channel by ssh to docker container, I am using DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN

- #runmqsc

DISPLAY CHANNEL(*)

Default password is ( as web console )

```
User: admin
Password: passw0rd
```

Details are referred at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/docs/developer-config.md

[Connection IP/Port/Channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwPwv.png)

[User ID/Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glu53.png)